# Typo3: How do I make a loop for each element in a table?

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-11.x

I have a Typo3(11.5.12) website, with a [generated sitepackage](https://sitepackagebuilder.com/new/) and the Fluid Template Engine.

I want to create a dynamic table element in a custom template. It is supposed to create an element for each entry a user makes on a the page in Typo3.

I tried to implement this with a table and I want to make an iterator, that loops once for each element added to this table in the custom html layout. In the loop I want to create an *option* element containing the text of the table row and a custom ID.

I already made an Iterator with fluid, that loops for each element in an array, so maybe converting the table content to an array might work?

If there is another content module that fits better I would use that, I also considered a simple text element with an iterator for each line.

I made a variable *content*, which gets the content of said table in the *setup.typoscript* file.

The table:

[image: table]

The variable in *setup.typoscript*:

```
variables{
            content < styles.content.get
}
```

The (current) content of the variable:

```html
<div id="c21" class="frame frame-default frame-type-table frame-layout-0"> 
  <table class="ce-table"> 
    <tbody> 
      <tr> <td> Testkunde 1 </td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td> Testkunde 2 </td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td> Testkunde 3 </td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td> Testkunde 4 </td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td> Testkunde 5 </td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td> Testkunde 6 </td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td> Testkunde 7 </td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td> Testkunde 8 </td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td> Testkunde 9 </td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td> Testkunde 10 </td> </tr> 
    </tbody> 
  </table> 
</div>
```

Snippet from the custom html layout, where I want to implement the iterator:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4">
                <input type="hidden" name="Select" value="All">
                <select name="Nr" size="20" style="width:400px;">
                    <option value="1">Kunde 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Kunde 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Kunde 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Kunde 4</option>
                    <option value="99"> {content}</option>
                    <!--I want to create an option element
                         for each line of the table here-->
                    
                </select>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would prefer to create an extension for it. If there are user entries (with a form?) and it should be created dynamically, you need more than a content element which is very static.

Comment: I see, I don´t want to use frontend user entries  with a form though, I want backend users to write in the table content itself.

Comment: So shall the snippet be shown inside a form created with the form extension? I understand the details, but the larger context is unclear for me.

Comment: The snippet is used in a custom html template for a page that shows a table with a set of data. I didn´t use the form extension so far. I want to show a static site, that I already made, with a dynamic table. The template is made with fluid, the snippet is in the *f:section name="Main"* part of the template. I want users to click on elements in the table to show specific content. To do that I need to give the *option*s different values, which I wanted to generate automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When manually rendering a backend-created text table, I built my own fluid view helper for this that wraps `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\CsvUtility::csvToArray`. Its result can easily be iterated on.